# critique on sentence construction

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

First post here. I wanted to thank one of the forum members in an online course I was attending for sharing his experience. I wrote this message.

> Thanks for sharing your experience. Its heartening to hear what you made out of this course. It would be great if more of the alumni **come forward** and **share** their experiences.

Should the highlighted verbs be Present or Past tense? Does it make any difference?

Please note that I am an ESL Student.

Comment: Hi sreenivas, welcome to ELL. For the future, note that ideally we'd prefer you only ask about a single issue on each question. Rest assured that ***the** alumni* is quite correct in this context, but idiomatically most native speakers would prefer ***came** forward and **shared***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your reply! Sure I will try to ask one issue per question next time.re: **came forward and shared** Yes, what you said make sense but can you give some explanation as to what makes it sound more correct. I tried googling but of no help.

Comment: @ sreenivas: English isn't designed by a committee working to a coherent set of principles, so mainly the explanation is simply "that's how people usually say it". Strictly, *"It **would be** good if you **were to** do something"*, but native speakers are increasingly less keen on such "subjunctive" constructions. As it's a hypothetical scenario, we prefer past tense, because present tense is more associated with the "real, here and now" world, rather than the "imaginary" one that **would** (not **does**) exist.

Comment: ...I've edited your question to focus on this specific point, so maybe it will be reopened and answered more thoroughly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your edit changed the meaning of the question. Originally, the OP asked about grammaticality, but focused on using _the_ before _alumni_; now the question is asking about using the present tense or the paste tense.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: He asked about *both* points, but the other issue (use of the definite article) is imho trivial. Plus very likely it's been asked before - but even if not, I'd probably vote to close it if that was all we were answering here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Still, in the current revision, "Particularly regarding the usage of 'the' in front of alumni and the word 'come forward'." is not anymore present. Using the definitive article is not trivial, IMO, for a English learner.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: If you think that issue is "not trivial", then by all means post a question yourself about it. I edited so *this* post only asks one question, which may lead to it being reopened. Naturally, I chose to keep the one which strikes me as potentially more problematic. But I'm a native speaker, obviously - if you as a non-native speaker see things differently, I don't understand why you closevoted in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't vote to close because the question asked about the article; I voted to close it for other reasons. And as usual, a question can be re-opened, if the OP opportunely rewrites the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You edited the question correctly. And the explanation make sense for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OP's context, the [modal auxiliary verb](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-would.htm) **would** establishes the "if-clause" as a *conditional, hypothetical* scenario. This can be reflected using the [subjunctive](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-subjunctive.htm) verb form (plus infinitive)...

> It would be good if they **were to come** forward

...but as that link says, *the subjunctive is a special, relatively rare verb form in English* - so in practice, native speakers tend to avoid it.

It's often said that English only really has two basic tenses - Present, and "non-Present" (usually, but sometimes misleadingly called Past tense). Because Present tense is more associated with the "real, here and now" world, rather than OP's "imaginary" scenario, we normally use **Simple Past**...

> *It [would be nice if he **came**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22would%20be%20nice%20if%20he%20comes%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22would%20be%20nice%20if%20he%20came%22&oq=%22would%20be%20nice%20if%20he%20came%22&gs_l=serp.3...3500.5512.0.5783.3.3.0.0.0.0.86.177.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.-GmlSUinlEk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.d2k&fp=9d9b30455b6c0f23&biw=1512&bih=907)* (3310 hits on Google Books)
>    *It [would be nice if he **comes**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22would%20be%20nice%20if%20he%20comes%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)* (1 hit)
>    *It [would be nice if he **were to come**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22would%20be%20nice%20if%20he%20comes%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22would%20be%20nice%20if%20he%20were%20to%20come%22&oq=%22would%20be%20nice%20if%20he%20were%20to%20come%22&gs_l=serp.3...1295560.1298251.1.1298611.9.9.0.0.0.0.77.451.9.9.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.8MdB0t0owIU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.d2k&fp=9d9b30455b6c0f23&biw=1512&bih=907)* (1 hit)
>
> *It [would be good if they **did**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22would%20be%20good%20if%20he%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22would%20be%20good%20if%20they%20did%22&oq=%22would%20be%20good%20if%20they%20did%22&gs_l=serp.3...5009.5760.3.6005.3.3.0.0.0.0.81.192.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.pD0kOFRugdA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.d2k&fp=9d9b30455b6c0f23&biw=1512&bih=907) that* (6740 hits)
>    *It [would be good if they do](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22would%20be%20good%20if%20he%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22would%20be%20good%20if%20they%20do%22&oq=%22would%20be%20good%20if%20they%20do%22&gs_l=serp.3...14424.19969.2.20372.8.8.0.0.0.0.236.652.7j0j1.8.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.q_nRO228lIA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.d2k&fp=9d9b30455b6c0f23&biw=1512&bih=907) that* (3 hits)
>    *It [would be good if they were to do](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22would%20be%20good%20if%20he%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22would%20be%20good%20if%20they%20were%20to%20do%22&oq=%22would%20be%20good%20if%20they%20were%20to%20do%22&gs_l=serp.3...1349310.1352810.4.1353256.13.13.0.0.0.0.116.789.12j1.13.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.IDIoGzjHKaw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.d2k&fp=9d9b30455b6c0f23&biw=1512&bih=907) that* (2 hits)

Comment: What about "it would be good if (they) would come forward"?

Comment: @Hellion: Well, it's certainly "grammatically valid" to simply repeat the modal verb. But again, I think it's just not a form we use very often. But I note [would be good if they would come](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22would+be+good+if+they+would+come%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) gets 4 hits, where there are only 8 for [would be good if they came](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22would+be+good+if+they+came%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)